# Pairing 5th generation iPod touch with Bluetooth-HID dongle and windows PC

Tags: ipod-touch, bluetooth

**Aim:**

- I am trying to pair my 5th generation iPod touch with windows PC.
- I also have a "Bluetooth to HID" USB dongle(connected to windows PC),
  which I am trying to pair with my iPOD touch. The dongle supports
  Bluetooth 2.1/2.0/1.2/1.1. It sends out a byte stream, which I want
  to read.

**Problem:**

- When I am trying to pair my 5th generation iPod touch with windows
  PC, even though everything goes fine on the PC side, my iPod is
  giving "Device not supported" error.
- My iPod is not even detecting
  the Bluetooth-HID dongle. Although my Mac-mini detects it, but I am
  unable to pair it.

**Findings till now:**

- When I searched, I read on [Apple discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4693854) that "The iPod does not have the necessary BT profiles to pair with a computer." On [another thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20777913#20777913) it says, "It only support bluetooth for stereo headphone/speakers, some peer to peer apps from the app store, some keyboards." Fair enough.

If iPod cannot actually pair with the PC or the Bluetooth-HID dongle, are their ANY Apple devices which are capable of doing the same? Again my main aim is to read the byte stream from the dongle for which pairing seems necessary.

I would be really thankful if you could please share your experience and provide some guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can get the BT Stack needed to connect to pc but only if you jailbreak your iPod Touch 5Th gen.
 you can do this simply with pangu and iOS 8.x and you just search for BT Stack in Cydia and install that and you should be good to go.